# My breadcrumbs are skipping a level

Tags: routes

I've got a Main Menu and am using Superfish, not sure if this makes any difference.

But in the breadcrumbs the top level of the main menu is being skipped. Eg.

Instead of

Home - A - B

My breadcrumb looks like:

Home - B

B, being the page I am currently on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal core breadcrumbs can be flaky at times.

You may be interested in

1. [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) ( contrib module )
2. [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) ( contrib module )
3. hook_preprocess_breadcrumb ( theme preprocess function, set `$variables['breadcrumb']` )
4. [theme_breadcrumb](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) ( theme function )

Using one or more of those methods, you can control breadcrumb behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for that. Custom Breadcrumbs alone didn't fix the problem. Menu Position looks a bit complicated :(
This is how the breadcrumbs are being generated.
<ol><li><a href="/">Home</a> › </li><li><a href="/node"></a> › </li><li><a href="/content/mypage">My page?</a> › </li><li>Edit</li></ol>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Easy Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb)

> Easy Breadcrumb uses the current URL (path alias) and the current
>   page's title to automatically extract the breadcrumb's segments and
>   its respective links. Easy Breadcrumb is really a plug and play
>   module, it auto-generates the breadcrumb by using the current URL, the
>   user needs to do anything to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This module, [Menu BreadCrumb](https://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb), allows you to disable menus and re-order the weight in which they are used to create your breadcrumb trail. A very simple solution if you are using more than one menu containing the menu item on the same page. Although, if you are using multilingual menu modules you might have to apply [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/1414900#comment-7384638)